# How can I get Lat/Lng of two points (train station) on google maps?

Tags: google-maps

I'm about to trace with direction service the railway between two station.
The problem is I can't get the Lat/Lng of the two station, it get always a neighbour points.

The route is (search on google maps website) :

```
Ceres, TO to Stazione Porta Nuova, Corso Vittorio Emanuele II, 58, Torino
```

I need Lat/Lng of Ceres (train station) and Stazione Porta Nuova, Corso Vittorio Emanuele II, 58, Torino (train station). How can I get them?

So I can draw in my maps the same railway (brown line).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class GetXMLTask
{
    static double longitute;
    static double latitude;
    public JSONObject getLocationInfo(String address)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try 
        {
            address = address.replaceAll(" ","%20");    
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false");
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            response = client.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) 
            {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            Log.i("getLocationInfo ClientProtocolException", e.toString());
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.i("getLocationInfo IOException", e.toString());
        }
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try 
        {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            Log.i("getLocationInfo JSONException", e.toString());
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getLatLong(JSONObject jsonObject) 
    {
        ArrayList<Double> latlng = new ArrayList<Double>();

        try 
        {
            longitute = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng");
            latitude = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");
            latlng.add(latitude);
            latlng.add(longitute);
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            longitute = 0;
            latitude = 0;
            Log.i("getLatLong", e.toString());
        }
        return latlng;
    }
}


now we can call it inside our class by

latitude = new GetXMLTask().getLatLong(new GetXMLTask().getLocationInfo(address)).get(0);
longitude = new GetXMLTask().getLatLong(new GetXMLTask().getLocationInfo(address)).get(1);
```

I may not have the super optimised code , but this is working pretty fine for me , give it a try , just passed the address in your calling class